# Html5 postMessage using jQuery, but not jQuery-postMessage script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

So I was messing around with the Html5 PostMessage sample at [Html5 Demos](http://html5demos.com/postmessage2) and I created a sample [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shelbyz/Ksd7R/) to see if I understood how it worked together.

The demo makes use of `document.getElementById(...)` which I thought could be replaced with the jQuery selector `$("#...")`, but I got stuck on the because the returned object from the jQuery select does not have access to `contentWindow` while `document.getElementById(...)` does.

```
document.getElementById("frame1").contentWindow.postMessage("Hello from another domain", "http://dl.dropbox.com"); // works

$("#frame1").contentWindow.postMessage("Hello from another domain", "http://dl.dropbox.com"); // no dice
```

I'm not entirely well versed in jQuery to know which of the many methods to call on the results object from the selector to get back to the result I would see from `document.getElementById(...)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$("#frame1")    // This a jQuery object that encapsulate the DOM element.
$("#frame1")[0] // this is the DOM element.
//Or
$("#frame1").get(0) // this is the DOM element.
```

Full code:

```
$("#frame1")[0].contentWindow.postMessage("Hello from another domain", "http://dl.dropbox.com"); // DICE!
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ksd7R/4/)

But I find it awkward to use jQuery to select by `id` then extract the DOM element out of it, and not using jQuery at all. what's wrong with `document.getElementById`? those 15 extra chars?

Comment: Nothing in particular.  I was just trying to figure out why what the result I was getting from jQuery was not matching up with document.getElementById(...).

Comment: @ShelbyZ. because `$()` constructs jQuery objects and not retrieving the DOM element, like `document.getElementById`

Comment: I feel like my jQuery experience has been mostly a hack till it works as opposed to learning how exactly the data returned is formatted.  It makes more sense now.

Comment: @ShelbyZ. then you should take a tour on the [jQuery API site](http://api.jquery.com/), couple of hours and you're a jQuery ninja! it's not a hard library to understand.